# Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin passing value as "VALUE"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" to trigger child job. I am passing predefined parameter as NUMBER=$VERSION_NUMBER and child job failed saying FILE_NAME."12345" do not exist. I went to location and found property file is there and realized that child job is searching properties file as FILE_NAME."12345"(FILE_NAME.$NUMBER) and actual name of file is FILE_NAME.12345, So root cause seems like that pligin is passing value with "".

Please suggest if there is a way to pass value without "".

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

try using ${NUMBER} instead of $NUMBER